# Template does not work when it is not in the main class

Tags: c++

I have tried using a template in a class but it works in the main class.

Here is my main class:

```
#include "AddSubtract.cpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    templEx();
}
```

And here is the class where the template is located:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void Print(T value)
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

void templEx() {
    Print("Venezuela");
}
```

And here are the errors which I get:

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Suppression State
Error   LNK2005 "void __cdecl templEx(void)" (?templEx@@YAXXZ) already defined in AddSubtract.obj   ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\bahge\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Source1.obj 1   Build*

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Suppression State
Error   LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found  ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\bahge\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe   1   Build*

Comment: Note: That's not the main class, that's the `main` *function*.

Comment: Tip: Don't `#include` `.cpp` files. It messes a lot of things up, like precisely this. You should only ever have to include header files, typically `.h` though `.hpp` is also used.

Comment: OK I wil edit the question

Comment: I will fix that @tadman

Comment: You need to move the template definition to a header file and `#include` it or the `main()` function will not know what you're talking about.

Comment: Do you still have the same error with this recently-edited code?  Your error looks like something that would result from including a cpp file, and your revised main file looks like it would produce different errors now..

Comment: Add this to main.cpp `extern void templEx();`

Comment: I have rolled back the edit to this question so the code, the error, and the accepted answer once again match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're compiling that code that defines `tmplEx` once in the `main.cpp` and additionally in the secondary source file, which leads to the conflict.

Define the template in a separate header file that both can `#include` as necessary.

Comment: OK I will fix that and check if it fixes the issue

Comment: Making `templEx` `inline` would be an alternative...

Comment: @fabian A messy solution to an otherwise simple fix.

Comment: You could say the same about introducing another source file or about possibly taking away a possibility for the compiler to optimize out such a simple function... Not saying your solution isn't good, but there ***are*** scenarios where a `inline` function should be chosen.

Comment: @fabian For sure, `inline` is helpful in some situations, but this function is trivial and does not need such treatment. It's best left in a source file and compiled separately, and doing that habitually leads to far less cluttered code.